# sudo apt update got 404 at GCP Compute Engine VM

Tags: docker

I'm installing Docker in a GCP Compute Engine VM, but I have some obstacles.

This is my first time doing this, can anyone help.

```
fdtigermaster@fdtigermaster-dev-gcp-test:~$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease  
Hit:2 http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease                       
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease                                       
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian mantic InRelease                                        
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic InRelease  
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian mantic Release              
       404  Not Found [IP: 13.226.22.98 443]        
         Reading package lists... Done          
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian mantic Release' does not have a Release file.   
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.   
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And I also tried:

```
sudo sed -i 's/debian/ubuntu/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo sed -i 's|docker.com/linux/debian|docker.com/linux/ubuntu|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: The source https://download.docker.com/linux/debian supports only Debian; you can quickly see that by opening the link in your provided paste; where you'll note no support for *mantic* or any Ubuntu release. https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ contains the Ubuntu support (*which if you look has support for mantic*).

Comment: @guiverc This is my ubuntu image from GCP ubuntu-minimal-2310-mantic-amd64-v20231030

Comment: My comment relates to you adding a source `https://download.docker.com/linux/debian ` which is INVALID for a Ubuntu system, being valid only for DEBIAN...   Your issue is as per the duplicate; you added an incorrect source; it needs to be removed & the correct source (*provided in my prior comment*) added in its place.  Ubuntu images do not include 3rd party sources which that one is.

Comment: @guiverc The linked Q/A need to be updated. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Then read the official documentation here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu, you've added a source that is **not** for Ubuntu and doesn't support your release; that was the mistake; you need to reverse the steps you used to add that non-Ubuntu source to your system. The answer is in the duplicate in my opinion; you just need to adjust it for the source you added over the examples in that question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/ect/apt/sources.list` and the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` dir then remove any related docker's sources.

Follow the official documentation : [Set up Docker's apt repository.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/):

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal an backup your repositories list.
`cd /etc/apt`
`sudo nano sources.list` just so you can see what's in there.
`sudo cp sources.list sources.list.backup`
Then reset using this method
`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
 and report back.

Comment: I also do all about it but still the same error，Maybe I try to uninstall all the docker file and install again

Comment: When in doubt, watch a youboob presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZZrjbHZCAI